# Program/shortcut for "Move window to this monitor" - Windows 10 / 11

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, power-management, window, window-manager

Is there a shortcut / right click option, or a program that adds shortcut / GUI option, to move a window to the current monitor?

I know I can hover on a program on the taskbar, right click the little preview window, and then click `Move` to be able to use the arrow keys to reposition a window.

However, some programs just switch to the window when I right click the preview window (e.g. VS Code).

Besides, I find it very tedious.

Is there a program / add-on that would just add a right click option `Move to this screen`? Or maybe a program that adds a shortcut that allows me to do this in some other way?